# In mvvm can we call viewmodel's methods from view?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am trying to retrieve uri parameters in my viewmodels. I tried severals things but nothing works as expected... I would like to mimic OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom methods of Page so I wrote :

In my ViewBase class (inherited from Page) :

```
public ViewModelBase ViewModel
{
    get { return this.DataContext as ViewModelBase; }
    protected set
    {
        if (value != this.DataContext)
        {
            this.DataContext = value;
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    this.ViewModel.OnNavigatedFrom(e.Uri);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    this.ViewModel.OnNavigatedTo(e.Uri);
}
```

and in my ViewModelBase class :

```
public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(Uri uri)
{
}

public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(Uri uri)
{
}
```

What is wrong if I do that ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Typically in MVVM you would use some form of commanding or an alternative that many MVVM frameworks provide.  I would seriously consider using an MVVM framework such as [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), or [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).  They all have their own mechanisms for invoking verbs on your view model from the view.